# Why you don't need to change the Java class in loosely coupling?

Tags: java, dependencies, coupling

I'm a Java developer and I try to understand the coupling in Java, tightly coupling vs loosely coupling. There are a lot of information and the definition is simple: Coupling – the degree of dependency between the components. If more dependency is there it’s considered tightly coupling, if less dependency is there it’s considered loosely coupling.

But when I look at the example I don't understand it. For ex this website https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coupling-in-java/

**tight coupling example**

```
class Volume  
{ 
     public static void main(String args[])  
     { 
         Box b = new Box(5,5,5); 
         System.out.println(b.volume); 
     } 
} 
class Box  
{ 
     public int volume; 
     Box(int length, int width, int height)  
     { 
         this.volume = length * width * height; 
     } 
}
```

"Explanation:In the above example, there is a strong inter-dependency between both the classes. If there is any change in Box class then they reflects in the result of Class Volume."

**loose coupling example**

```
class Volume  
{ 
     public static void main(String args[])  
     { 
         Box b = new Box(5,5,5); 
         System.out.println(b.getVolume()); 
     } 
} 
final class Box  
{ 
     private int volume; 
     Box(int length, int width, int height)  
     { 
         this.volume = length * width * height; 
     } 
     public int getVolume()  
     {  
         return volume;  
           
     } 
}
```

"Explanation : In the loosely coupling program, there is no dependency between both the classes. If we change anything in the Box classes then we don't have to change anything in Volume class."

But this is not true, if we change the class Box for ex we add another parameter in the constructor like here:

```
 Box(int length, int width, int height, int b)  
 { 
     this.volume = length * width * height + b; 
 }
```

Then we need to change the class Volume otherwise there will be compilation errors:

```
     Box b = new Box(5,5,5,3);
```

So, these changes should be done for both examples tightly coupling and also loosely coupling. What are they referring when they are saying you don't need to change something in the Volume class? Any feedback will be appreciated!

Comment: The examples doesn't illustrate coupling for object creation, but rather for object usage. In the second example, the internal state and implementation is hidden from the users of the class. How the `Box` class implements the `getVolume()` function is unknown from the outside, and it doesn't actually matter at all for the users of the class. If the implementation of the `getVolume` function, or how it stores the volume (the `volume` member variable) changes, that doesn't matter for the users.

Comment: There is a lot of poor quality stuff on Geeks-for-Geeks.  That example is actually an example of strong versus weak encapsulation, IMO.

Comment: @StephenC where can I find a good example of loosely coupled and tightly coupled? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with examples of tight (strong) versus weak (loose) coupling is that they tend to conflate the concepts of coupling and data abstraction.  These are related concepts ... but they are not the same thing.

In the example you found<sup>1</sup>, the most important problem with the "tight coupling" case is that the `Box.volume` field is declared as `public`.  This *allows* other code to directly use that field, and it means that the other code can depend on the name and type (and implied semantics) of the field.

By contrast, the "loose coupling" case declares that field as `private`, which removes the possibility of other code depending on the actual field.  Of course, we have replaced it with a getter method (`int getVolume()`), and there will still be coupling between the two classes.  But we have removed the possibility of coupling between the actual (now private) field and the classes that consume the volume.  And for the sake of argument, we could change the `Box` class to store the box dimensions and compute the volume on the fly; e.g.

```
class Box { 
     private int length, width, height; 
     Box (int length, int width, int height) { 
         // check the arguments are >= 0 and set the fields  
     }
     public int getVolume() {  
         return length * width * height;    
     } 
}
```

But how does this relate to data abstraction?  Well in the version above with private fields, some other class can't assign values to the fields directly.  But if they were public, other classes could change the box dimensions ... and even assign nonsense values to them, resulting in (say) the `getVolume` returning a negative volume.

---

Note that in an example like this it is not possible remove all coupling.  And whenever you have *any* coupling at all, that means that *some* changes to a class will inevitably require changes to others.

Your counter-example seems to be arguing that since adding a 4th parameter (dimension?) to `Box` will entail changing `Volume`.  That is true.  But it does not mean that the "loose coupling" example is invalid.  The proposition was that the "loose" version was less coupled than the "tight" version.  It was NOT that there was no coupling at all.

And indeed, if you add the 4th parameter to `Box` in your "tight" version in the obvious way, the same changes will need to be made to `Volume`.  For >that< change, our reduction in coupling by hiding of the `volume` field is neutral.  But it is not neutral for the change embodied in my version above!

---

To sum it up, coupling is a matter of degree.  Coupling between modules (classes, whatever) cannot be removed entirely ... if they need to work together.  What you really need to focus on is coupling that makes it harder to understand and maintain a code base; e.g. coupling that is unnecessary, unexpected or hidden from the programmer in some way.

---

<sup>1 - I commented that the example you found is a poor one.  In fact, the real problem is in the explanation that you quoted.  That explanation is simply incorrect.  I don't recommend Geeks-for-Geeks as a source of information.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for explanation! So the loosely coupling ex is less coupled than the tightly coupling ex because some other class can't assign values to the field volume directly. On the GeekForGeek, there is another ex with Topic and Subject, but without dependency injection, I can't see much difference, and if we want to change from Topic1 to Topic2 we need to change only the object to Topic2, and the reference variable will remain the same t. Is it a less coupled ex like this without DI (the object is created manually with new keyword) or only when we use DI we could say we have loosely coupling?

Comment: *"So the loosely coupling ex is less coupled than the tightly coupling ex because some other class can't assign values to the field volume directly."* - Or access it.  Or depend on it (directly) in any other way.

Comment: I'm not going to talk about another example.  And I've already told you what I think of Geeks-for-Geeks as a source of ... knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Objects have an API - their public-facing parts that anyone can use. If you add some new mandatory thing to the API, or remove some parts, then calling code will most likely have to be updated too. But not all changes to a class have to change the API. For example, consider what happens if you want to store the individual dimensions in your `Box` class, not the volume (you probably don't want to store both, because that's unnecessary duplication - if one of the dimensions changes, you will have to recalculate the volume anyway). In the tight coupling scenario, there's no way to keep `Main` unchanged after that change. In the loose coupling scenario, you're adding new `private` fields for the dimensions and changing the implementation of `getVolume()`, but `Main` doesn't care about that and doesn't change.